# typescript generic function return type from paramaters

Tags: typescript

I want dynamic return type from parameters.

```
type TestType = {
    value1: string,
    value2: number
}

function testFn1<T extend TestType>(...pick:(keyof T)[]): ??? { }

//testFn<TestType>("value1")  expect {value1: string}
//testFn<TestType>("value1","value2") expect {value1: string, value2:number}
```

Plz

How can i define function return type?

I try below.

```
function test3<T, K extends keyof T>(...vars: K[]): Record<K, string | number>
```

but this return Just T

Answer (score 0):

For the return type, you can use the [`Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).

But what you also need is to actually pass a `T` to the function. One, so the function actually has an object to pick values from, and two, so the compiler can infer `T`.

With that, this works:

```
function test<T, K extends keyof T>(t: T, ...vars: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  // ...
}

const t: TestType = fromSomewhere();

const result = test(t, "value1", "value2");
console.log(result.value1);
console.log(result.value2)

const result2 = test(t, "value1");
console.log(result2.value1);
console.log(result2.value2); // error, as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does not have partial type inference. If you provide `TestType` explicitly to `T`, it can not infer other generic types via argument types.

One work-around would be to use currying. You can explicitly provide `TestType` as the generic type in the first function call while the second call infers `K` with the arguments.

```
function testFn<T extends TestType>() {
    return <K extends keyof T>(...pick: K[]): { [Key in K]: T[Key] } => {
        return null!
    }
}

const result1 = testFn<TestType>()("value1")
const result2 = testFn<TestType>()("value1","value2")
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbmgXigbwLACgr6gDcBDAGwFcIBGALikQCcBLAOwHMAaXAosygJjotyAWwBGEBrgC+uOTgBm5FgGNgTAPYsowBMABiLADwwoEAB66WAE3iw9ySAD4AFAEpM3AgwjByDbSMAaTNLCBs7AGsIEA0FWFcAOmSwJhVIuiCAbQBdNzoMKCygmKhWKCCcuhhimJyoaShUJ088Hm9ff21hUlIAQi98WRxh3BUtRCgfeHJSYComnT1DEwcUVzcXACISCmottzGJ4CmEWeB+Rd1EFbhERwgN7d3KKi2OHb4IfgOgA)